# How to select all record in TableA where not in TableB but filter group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables, Student, Group and StudentGroup.

 Student can have more than 1 group.

**Sample Data**

```
Student
Id  | Name
01    StudentA     
02    StudentB
03    StudentC

Group
Id  | Name
11    Group1
12    Group2
13    Group3

StudentGroup
Id  | Group_Id   | Group_Name   | Student_id | Student_Name
21         11      Group1             01       StudentA
22         11      Group1             02       StudentB
23         12      Group2             03       StudentC
24         13      Group3             02       StudentB    
25         11      Group1             03       StudentC    
26         13      Group3             01       StudentA
```

How can I get some Student do not have relation with some selected All Group.

 **==== Sample1 ====**

 Student = 02,03

 Group   = 12,13

I select (02,03)Student and (12,13)Group.

then I want just Student record that don't have selected group (12,13) in StudentGroup.

```
StudentGroup
Id  | Group_Id   | Group_Name   | Student_id | Student_Name
23         12      Group2             03       StudentC
24         13      Group3             02       StudentB
26         13      Group3             01       StudentA
```

**Expected result**

```
StudentB
StudentC
```

selected group is 12,13

don't get StudentA cause we select student 02,03

get StudentB because it has relate with Group3 but don't with Group2 (selected Group = 12,13)

get StudentC reason same StudentB

**==== Sample2 ====**

 Student = 01,03

 Group   = 11,13

```
StudentGroup
Id  | Group_Id   | Group_Name   | Student_id | Student_Name
21         11      Group1             01       StudentA
22         11      Group1             02       StudentB
24         13      Group3             02       StudentB    
25         11      Group1             03       StudentC    
26         13      Group3             01       StudentA
```

**Expected result**

```
StudentC(03)
```

We select Student 01 ,03,

but StudentA(01) have relate with all selected Group(11,13) so don't want StudentA.

StudentC(03) have relate with Group1 but don't have relate with Group3 so get StudentC.

**Then I try**

```
SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE Id in ('02','03')
AND Id NOT IN (
        SELECT SG.Student_id
        FROM Group G
        LEFT JOIN StudentGroup SG
        ON G.Id = SG.Group_Id
        WHERE G.Id IN ('12','13') 
 )
```

But sound like don't work cause it's get ONLY Student don't have data in StudentGroup.

 **I try**

 to use `RANK () OVER ( PARTITION BY Student_id )`

 expected to get Student_id in same rank where Student_id = Null (means not in StudentGroup).

 BUT when it NULL I can't get it.

```
StudentGroup
Id  | Group_Id   | Group_Name   | Student_id | Student_Name
           11      Group1             03       StudentA
           12      Group2             03       StudentC
           13      Group3             NULL     NULL
```

So how can I achieve this? Thank for anyone who come in topic, who read and answer.

Comment: I am afraid your question is not understandable. In first case how you came up with StudentB, StudentC for example.

Comment: okay ,at first case I specifically select Student = 02,03 and Group = 12,13. then in StudentGroup table, I find selected Student that don't have all selected Group. In sample data have (StudentGroup id=24)(Group3,StudentB) but don't have (Group2,StudentB) . if have (Group2,StudentB) result is only StudentC. Thank You.

Comment: Hmm probably it is only you that understands what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Since `studentgroup` table has both `student_id` and `group_id` column `group` table is not needed to be joined.

By inner joining `Student` and `StudentGroup` table with where clause we got the students which are in any of those groups. But to remove students who is available in both the groups we have used `having` clause.

(Please don't use reserved word as table or column name. It's not a good practice. Group is a reserved word.)

```
 create table Student(Id  varchar(10), Name varchar(50));
 insert into Student values('01'    ,'StudentA');     
 insert into Student values('02'    ,'StudentB');
 insert into Student values('03'    ,'StudentC');
 
 create table [Group] (Id  int, Name varchar(50));
 insert into [Group] values(11 ,   'Group1');
 insert into [Group] values(12 ,   'Group2');
 insert into [Group] values(13 ,   'Group3');
 
 create table StudentGroup(Id  int, Group_Id   int, Group_Name  varchar(50), Student_id varchar(10), Student_Name varchar(50));
 insert into StudentGroup values(21,         11,      'Group1',             '01'       ,'StudentA');
 insert into StudentGroup values(22,         11,      'Group1',             '02'       ,'StudentB');
 insert into StudentGroup values(23,         12,      'Group2',             '03'       ,'StudentC');
 insert into StudentGroup values(24,         13,      'Group3',             '02'       ,'StudentB'); 
 insert into StudentGroup values(25,         11,      'Group1',             '03'       ,'StudentC');    
 insert into StudentGroup values(26,         13,      'Group3',             '01'       ,'StudentA');
```

Query #1

```
 select s.name from student s inner join studentgroup sg on s.id=sg.student_id
 where s.id in ('02','03') and group_id in (12,13)
 group by s.name
 having count(distinct group_id)<2
```

Output:

| name |
| --- |
| StudentB |
| StudentC |

Query #2

```
 select s.name from student s inner join studentgroup sg on s.id=sg.student_id
 where s.id in ('01' ,'03') and group_id in (11,13)
 group by s.name
 having count(distinct group_id)<2
 GO
```

OUtput:

| name |
| --- |
| StudentC |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a23d78a9b5f10f80d77224613338b442)*

Comment: Thank you for reply. I will try and then come back to show result.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please let me know your feed-back.

Comment: okay. your solution is worked! but I miss one case, when in StudentGroup table don't have any data relate with Student. I want them too. Exam.. When I Select (id = 26 ,Name = StudentZ) but no data in StudentGroup. I expect result have StudentZ too. then I us 'union' [Student(id) not in (StudentGroup)] with your query. I think it work fine now. so thank you.

Comment: Great job. best wishes.